# How to split math operators from numbers in a string

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to split between operators and float/int values in a string.

Example:

```
$input = ">=2.54";
```

Output should be:

`array(0=>">=",1=>"2.54");` .

Operators cases : >,>=,<,<=,=

I tried something like this:

```
$input = '0.2>';
$exploded = preg_split('/[0-9]+\./', $input);
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working version using `preg_split`:

```
$input = ">=2.54";
$parts = preg_split("/(?<=[\d.])(?=[^\d.])|(?<=[^\d.])(?=[\d.])/", $input);
print_r($parts);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => >=
    [1] => 2.54
)
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used, which says to split when:

```
(?<=[\d.])(?=[^\d.])  a digit/dot precedes and a non digit/dot follows
|                     OR
(?<=[^\d.])(?=[\d.])  a non digit/dot precedes and a digit/dot follows
```

That is, we split at the interface between a number, possibly a decimal, and an arithmetic symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$input = ">=2.54";
preg_match("/([<>]?=?) ?(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)/",$input,$exploded);
```

Comment: I tried that on int values and its not working, such as : $input = "=5";

Comment: Try this `preg_match("/([<>]?=?) ?(\d*(?:\.\d+)?)/",$input,$exploded);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split between the operators, you might use and [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match the variations of the operators, and use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

This will give you the position to split on. Then assert using [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that there is a digit on the left or on the right.

```
\d\K(?=[<>=])|(?:>=?|<=?|=)\K(?=\d)
```

**Explanation**

- `\d\K(?=[<>=])` Match a digit, forget what was matched and assert either `<`, `>` or `=` on the right
- `|` Or
- `(?:>=?|<=?|=)\K(?=\d)` Match an operator, forget what was matched and assert a digit on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L7OrS1/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/KCqVL)

For example

```
$strings = [
    ">=2.54",
    "=5",
    "0.2>"
];

$pattern = '/\d\K(?=[<>=])|(?:>=?|<=?|=)\K(?=\d)/';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    print_r(preg_split($pattern, $string));
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => >=
    [1] => 2.54
)
Array
(
    [0] => =
    [1] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0.2
    [1] => >
)
```